# Change an attribute of all elements expect the ones which have an specific parent by CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Please consider this sample.

I want to change the `color` of all tables to `red`, except the ones which are inside a `div` with specific class named `modal` with `css`

The `color` of all tables should change:

```
<table>
.....
</table>
```

The table inside `div` modal should not be change:

```
<div class="modal">
   <table>
    .....
   </table>
</div>
```

I used below css:

```
table:not(div.modal){
  color : red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zLu5ygzo/

It seems quite simple but it does not work !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give this way:

```
:not(.modal) > table {
  color: red;
}
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yrrw61u4/**

```css
:not(.modal) > table {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<b> The color of table fonts must be red:</b>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table> 
<p/>
<b>This is a table in a div with modal class and color must not be changed:</b>
<div class="modal">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The filter selector is on the `<div>` and not on the `<table>`...

Else reset to use something like this:

```
table {
  color: red;
}
.modal table {
  color: black;   /* Reset */
}
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wo40cpxo/**

```css
table {
  color: red;
}
.modal table {
  color: black;   /* Reset */
}
```

```html
<b> The color of table fonts must be red:</b>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table> 
<p/>
<b>This is a table in a div with modal class and color must not be changed:</b>
<div class="modal">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do it :

```css
table {
    color : red;
}

.modal table {
    color : black;
}
```

```html
<b> The color of table fonts must be red:</b>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table> 
<p/>
<b>This is a table in a div with modal class and color must not be changed:</b>
<div class="modal">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</div>
```

See [**the Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zLu5ygzo/1/).

Comment: Is there any way to make it work with :not selector?

Comment: @Sowmya : Yes. That would be `:not(.modal) > table {color: red;}`. I do not recommend doing it that way, though!

Comment: @Sowmya : What browser are you using for testing?